# wc3270 not changing screen mode

Tags: display, telnet, terminal-emulator

I work with a process in an IBM i system that implies a change in the screen mode. When I login, I entered 24x80 mode, and after a couple of screens, I get to a listing that is 27x132 mode. In the IBM iAccessClient, I have no problems when passing from one screen to another. But when I use wc3270, I get the following error:

```
Ha aparecido el mensaje de error CPF4169 durante OPEN para el archivo...
```

Googling this code I get that this has to do with this change in screen mode. I tried using the option model, but nothing changes. If I use model 5 (27x132), the emulator opens in 132 col mode, but I get the error anyway.

Also, wc3270 has in its documentation the options altscreen and defscreen. I tried to use them, both single and at the same time, but i get an error. For instance:

> wc3270 SISTEMA -model 3279-2 -altscreen 27x132=\E[?40h\E[?3h
> Unknown or incomplete option: '-altscreen'
> Usage: wc3270 [options] [prefix:][LUname@]hostname[:port]
> wc3270 [options] [.s3270]
> Use --help for the list of options
> I also tried every variation (--altscreen, -altscreen, --altScreen, --altscreen, 127x32, 32x127)